# Inheritance of annotations in custom gradle tasks

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am writing some gradle plugins for a multi module project. Some of them are introducing tasks, which shall be considered as copy task. Of course they do the copy but also some other stuff.

My question is a more general one. Do I have to write a my own task action method calling the super task action? Or does gradle automatically call the task action of the super class?
To stick with the copy task:

```
class MyCopyTask extends Copy {

    public MyCopyTask () {
        super()
        from "just/a/default/path"
        into "another/default/path"

    }

    @TaskAction
    def myCopy() {
        super.copy()
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me how gradle decides what methods are executed in the execution phase. Do I need the method "myCopy" and why do I need it or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every concrete task class needs to have a method annotated with `@TaskAction`, which will be called by Gradle when the task is to be executed. Super methods annotated with `@TaskAction` will not be called.

Subclassing concrete task types such as `Copy` is rarely necessary/appropriate. Instead of implementing a task type such as `MyCopyTask`, consider to implement a plugin that adds a task of type `Copy`, or a task type that doesn't inherit from `Copy` but calls `project.copy()` inside its task action (composition over inheritance).

Comment: Concerning your comment "Subclassing concrete task types such as Copy is rarely necessary/appropriate.", when would you consider it to be the correct decision?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the `@TaskAction` annotation, custom gradle classes do inherit gradle annotations. For example, if you created an abstract task that defines inputs, you can annotate those inputs with `@Input` in the abstract class, add a `@CacheableTask` at the class level, then any class that extends it will inherit those as part of it's caching.

This also works with interfaces, such as with plugins.